# How to generate pseudo random number between A to B (A,B are int)in GNU C just with standard library

Tags: c, random

How to generate pseudo random number between A to B (A,B are int)in GNU C just with standard library

Thank you !

Comment: `int rand() {return 4;}`

Comment: @Anon: [link](http://www.xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming A < B then what about this...

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
r = (rand()%(B-A)) + A;
```

As per the comments below, it is possible that B-A is, in fact, greater than RAND_MAX. In this case you will have to be more careful.

Comment: Commenting on my own answer here, but to clarify, Karl K. is correct, the srand function need only be called once.

Comment: Be careful if your interval `B - A` is greater than `RAND_MAX + 1`.  In that case values of `r` won't be distributed uniformly, the maximal value of `r` will be `RAND_MAX + A`.

Comment: He said A and B are ints and I have never seen a RAND_MAX smaller than the max int. I guess you're right but I am going to assume that to be a very edge case.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `RAND_MAX` couldn't be less than `MAX_INT`, so, unfortunately, it really could.  For example, in typical MinGW configuration `RAND_MAX` is equal to `0x7FFF`.

Comment: @ib: thanks for the info there that is good to know. I updated my answer with a disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

You should seed the random number generator with `srand` **only once**, and then obtain random numbers with `rand`. The `rand` function returns numbers from 0 up to some constant `RAND_MAX`; you are responsible for mapping the results onto the desired range. The traditional way to do this is with the modulus operator, which gives the remainder that results from an integer division. So if you want 7 different results, for example, then you take `rand() % 7` and the result will be one of (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) - the possible remainders when dividing by 7. (Note that there are 7 of these.) Then you add an offset to create the desired range of results, as in Andrew White's example.

The easiest way to ensure that `srand` is called just once is to do it at or near the beginning of main().

For more information, see the documentation for these functions.

Comment: GNU C is a dialect of C which provides a number of extensions not present in the standard (such as the ability to define a function within the scope of another function).

Comment: I stand corrected. Edited accordingly (removed that bit). Is there an actual specification somewhere, or is this simply defined *de facto* by GCC compiler extensions?